# Joomla contact form not working.

Tags: joomla, phpmailer, joomla3.5

I am new with Joomla 3.5 and I'm already set up a contact form on my Joomla but the problem is I no receive any email from my localhost. I searched on several forums but I didn't find an answer to my problem. First thing I want to know is if it's possible to send an email with a local web server. Secondly, is it possible to send the mails to a gmail address and, if yes, what parameters - and where- do I have to change.I don't want to use STMP and it only allowed to use PHP mail. I am using Xampp Server.

Comment: For testing on localhost, it's probably easiest to set up Joomla to use SMTP. The mail settings are in the Global Configuration.

Comment: @NeilRobertson thank you for your help. I solved already.

Comment: @NeshMogan if you have solved, plase share the details here. Other people may face the same problem.

Comment: [link] (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/how-to/configure-email-over-smtp )

I use above link to solve. I use STMP Mailer. SMTP host use host email address , for my case I subscribe one account [link] (https://www.smartertools.com/smartermail/business-email-server) . Port set to STMP PORT which is port 25. Sometime port 25 might be blocked . Use this link to check your port [link](https://www.siteground.com/kb/smtp_port_25_blocked/ )